# CSS indent first line of text past the right edge

Tags: html, css, text-indent

It is possible to use `text-indent` property to indent the first line of text towards either side of left corner. Consider this example:

```css
h1 { text-indent: -200px; margin-left: 200px; }
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vehicula molestie imperdiet.</h1>
```

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                            Mauris   vehicula   molestie
                            imperdiet.
|---------- 200px ----------+------ 100% - 200px ------|
|-------------------------->| left margin
|<--------------------------| negative text indent
```

Is there a trick to do this the other way round:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris   vehicula   molestie
imperdiet.
|------ 100% - 200px ------+---------- 200px ----------|
```

What I want is the first line (and only the first line) of text to extend 200px past the left edge. Perhaps there is a similar CSS property which applies indenting around the right edge or applies to 2nd and latter lines of text.

[**Here is a jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/SAZ67/)

Comment: negative margin-left + width:increased ? codepen or jsfiddle to see your code is welcome :)

Comment: what is your issue? It will work as your expectation, I hope so if you didnt get result mention that too

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan: I cannot find a CSS property/hack that produces the desired output. First line of text must overflows outside the container towards the _right_, or in other words, the text inside heading must flow in **Γ** shape.

Answer (score 0):

text-indent could come from parent. with a padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/qsDST/

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    text-indent: -200px;
    padding-left:200px;
}
h1 {
    background: lime;
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
h1.other-way-round {
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-indent:0px
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SAZ67/3/)

**Second method**

```
h1.other-way-round{
    text-indent:0;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    left:-200px;
   }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SAZ67/6/)

Comment: no, the second and subsequent lines should be 100%-200px wide.

Comment: I have checked, sorry but it is not what I want.

Comment: Please look at the ascii art I posted. The second and subsequent lines must be less wider (e.g. 400px) than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

As I undarstand your expected result is something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. 
Mauris vehicula 
molestie imperdiet.
```

The easiest way to do this might be using Javascript.
You could detect the 2nd and past lines and wrap an tag around them with a padding-right of 200px.

You may need to use jQuery or simmilar to do this.

Badly it's not possible to set width/height nor padding to the `:first-line` pseudoelement.